# can we create html element with any tag or nodeName?

Tags: javascript, html, dom

Can we create Html element with any tag or nodeName using document.createElement() ?

And what happen if this is non-error? I mean can we manipulate it using javascript DOM API?

Answer (score -1):

No.

The DOM APIs do not provide any mechanism to make that possible.